# Working with psb in a psd

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images, file-format

**EDIT:** A Big update on this topic is presented with PS CC 14.2! Now you can have linked smart objects, it works like in InDesign. Just go to 'File → Place Linked' and choose your PSB file.

This is the Promo video from Adobe: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6AIgoFDwlk

---

Is it possible to import a PSB file (saved smart object) into several PSDs, so when I edit the PSB the change is visible in every PSD?

I only get it that way, that the PSB is copied into the PSD and the source PSB remains untouched.

Comment: your way is the only way i guess,lets hope to see another way.

Comment: a professional gamedeveloper said it should work, but he couldn't show me in lack of a computer

Comment: how come it is possible when you edit a PSB file and you want changes in PSD files? you have to do it manually on both files whereever i know :|

Comment: there may also be some confusion with your gamedev friend because Illustrator (and I think Flash & Fireworks also) supports linked files, but Photoshop does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*To Complete and answer my own question here is the update from last year:*

**Big update** on this topic is presented with PS CC 14.2! Now you can have linked smart objects, it works like in InDesign. Just go to `File->Place Linked…` and choose your .psb file.

This is the [promo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H6AIgoFDwlk) from Adobe.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, no.

There are numerous methods to import PDFs, AIs, other PSDs, PSBs, etc., but the "best" result is that imported objects are converted to "local"<sup>1</sup> `Smart Objects`.

@Johannes: the `File` → `Place` command converts the placed file into a `Smart Object` embedded in the current file.  Updating the original PSB/PSD does not update files that have placed it.  For whatever reason, the CS3-4 documentation does not mention this conversion but [Adobe finally made this correction in the CS5 documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WS7A1CFFDC-EDA1-489a-A1F8-068DD006FF7Ca.html).

<sup>1: By "Local" I mean the Smart Objects are saved in the file itself and become unique to the file in which they are saved</sup>

Comment: @Johannes No worries, I almost posted that as the answer but then I remembered having trouble with it a while ago.  Had to do a quick double-check to find out.  :-)