# One file with multiple linked files to one photoshop file

Tags: photoshop-scripting

I would like to create one psd file that has multiple layers containing a different piece of artwork, that is linked to another psd file containing multiple layers and each of those layers is linked to the layers in the first psd file.

For instance I have 5 dvd covers and 5 spines in one psd file. In the other psd file I have the artwork in layers for those covers and spines and these need to be easily swapped out.

Whats the simplest way of setting this up? I am more of an after effects person which if anyone knows, this process is very simple using precomps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I include a Photoshop file inside another Photoshop file?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/3636/how-can-i-include-a-photoshop-file-inside-another-photoshop-file)

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to create one psd file that has multiple layers containing a different piece of artwork, that is linked to another psd file containing multiple layers and each of those layers is linked to the layers in the first psd file.

This is the definition of **Photoshop Smart Objects**

[image]

- Select all the layers from the second psd
- Click the right mouse button and choose **Convert to Smart Object**
- Drag this Smart Object Layer to the composed psd file
- Close the previous psd file without saving
- Double click the **Smart Object Layer** to edit the psd file and its layers
- Make the changes to this file, save it and close it to see the changes in the composed file

In this example there are four Smart Objects, where editing the bottom-right one to hide the red ray layer:

[image]

More info at this question/answer about nesting Smart Objects: [Nesting Photoshop Smart Objects without losing the "link" between them?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/5194/120647)

Comment: I think the OP wants to have Linked Smart Objects: several layers (Linked SO's) shared between several psds so that changes in the linked SO would be reflected in  the psds